# Only first Label Not Showing on ASP.NET C# page

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, updatepanel

I have multiple asp.net labels inside 2 update panels.  I am handling them all the same but the first one does not show up.  For simplicity sake I have everything happening on one button when in reality the code happens in different places but I stepped through it in Debug and confirmed this is the order.  I am thinking it has to do with the 2 update panels, that a change it UpdatePanel3 doesn't update UpdatePanel2, but not sure.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelError" runat="server" 
            style="float: left" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

....

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelError2" runat="server" Text="Password" 
            style="float: left" Visible="False"></asp:Label>

        <asp:Button ID="ButtonShow" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                  onclick="ButtonShow_Click" />
                  </ContentTemplate>
```

In the code I do the following.

```
protected void ButtonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LabelError.Visible=true;
  LabelError2.Visible=true;

  LabelError.Style.Remove("display");
  LabelError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

  LabelError2.Style.Remove("display");


  if (LabelError.Visible)
  {
      LabelError.Text="This is Label Error";
      LabelError.Style.Add("display", "block");
  }
  else
  {
      LabelError.Style.Add("display", "none");
  }

  if (LabelError2.Visible)
  {
       LabelError2.Text="This is Label Error2";
       LabelError2.Style.Add("display", "block");
  }
  else
  {
      LabelError2.Style.Add("display", "none");
  }
}
```

LabelError2 pops on the screen.
LabelError does not.
Using IE, hitting F12 and looking at the DOM LabelError isn't even there.
What am I doing wrong?  Why won't LabelError show up?

Comment: Did you test the above code? It is working fine except event is renamed to **ButtonShow_Click**.

Comment: where is the function `ButtonShow_Click`?

Comment: Just updated question.  ButtonSubmit should have been ButtonShow.  I actually have 2 update panels.  I wonder if this is the cause of my problem?

Comment: Taking this theory into account I tried adding `UpdatePanel2.Update();` at the end of `ButtonShow_Click()` This worked.  It showed up.  Is this the right way to do this?  I feel like their should be a setting to update cross UpdatePanels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this theory into account I tried adding UpdatePanel2.Update(); at the end of ButtonShow_Click() This worked. It showed up.